# Trim audio files with Sox in milliseconds

Tags: audio, sox

Is there a way to trim the end of a file with SoX, in milliseconds, i have tried this:

```
sox tracks\5_7.mp3 ntracks\05_7.mp3 trim 2 2.195
```

But, it just says `End position is after expected end of audio` Even though the file is actually that long.

So im trying to make this song 2.000 seconds long, instead of 2.195, also, im doing this with 600+ files, so it needs to be done from the command line.

Heres my warnings:

```
sox WARN mp3: MAD lost sync"(this always happens, means nothing) 
sox WARN trim: Last 1 position(s) not reached (audio shorter than expected)
sox WARN sox: 'tracks\01_1.mp3' balancing clipped 3 samples; decrease volume?
```

This audio file goes for "00:00:02.19".

The line entered into the command line was:

```
sox -v3 tracks\01_1.mp3 ntracks\01_1.mp3 trim 2 0.19 pause
```

Here is my verbose start:

```
D:\Stuff\Habbo trax maker\trax maker\mp3support>sox -V3 tracks\01_1.mp3 ntracks\
01_1.mp3 trim 2 0.19
sox:      SoX v14.4.0

Input File     : 'tracks\01_1.mp3'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:02.19 = 96755 samples = 164.549 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 17.6k
Bit Rate       : 64.0k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)

sox INFO sox: Overwriting `ntracks\01_1.mp3'
sox INFO mp3: using MP3 encoding defaults

Output File    : 'ntracks\01_1.mp3'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 24-bit
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)
Comment        : 'Processed by SoX'

sox INFO sox: effects chain: input        44100Hz  1 channels
sox INFO sox: effects chain: trim         44100Hz  1 channels
sox INFO sox: effects chain: output       44100Hz  1 channels
sox WARN mp3: MAD lost sync
sox WARN trim: Last 1 position(s) not reached (audio shorter than expected).
```

Comment: Ok, i did the V verbose or verbatim or whatever start :P

Comment: Theres still a problem...
When i check the size of the audio, with a different program (because SoX only checks to the second decimal place) its about 0-99MilliSeconds off, is it possible to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, but, SoX doesn't show down to the millisecond, so i can't see if its accurate in SoX, thats why i checked it in another program :P and it was 2.036 seconds long.

Also, how can i stop mixing from changing the volume?

Comment: wav files are massive and ogg arnt supported in what im doing, my program has over 640 sound files.

I could, encode it to .wav, trim, then encode it back prehaps, would this work?

Comment: Looks like i won't be able to finnish my music program.. unless theres a C++ library that can join or trim sounds better :P
Actually can you make SoX overlay another sound after you have mixed it, so sound1 goes for 2.036 seconds, and sound 2 starts a 00:00:02.000 even though the other part hasnt stopped yet?

Comment: The extra samples in the mp3 file are an artifact of the encoding and will be removed by the decoder if encoder/decoder are compatible. [A similar question has been asked before](http://superuser.com/questions/400790/covert-wav-to-mp3-without-adding-silence-at-the-beginning).

Comment: Ok, so how can i make the encoder and decode compatible, i am inputting mp3 and outputting mp3. i tried using wav files, but it seems the dll i use only allows up to 500 wav files in the program :/

Comment: If its just data, and not actual audio, why does it increase the actual playtime, can't it just be separate data? :/

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you do all your processing in PCM and encode to mp3 later.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want to trim with millisecond precision, specify it:

```
sox in.mp3 out.mp3 trim 2 0.195
```

Saves 195 milliseconds with an offset of 2 seconds of `in.mp3` to `out.mp3`.

If you only want the first two seconds of the file use trim like this:

```
sox in.mp3 out.mp3 trim 0 2
```

If you want to skip the first two seconds of the file use trim like this:

```
sox in.mp3 out.mp3 trim 2
```

If you want to trim 195 milliseconds from the end of the file, use [*gerald's*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14297223/1331399) answer.

Excerpt from the manual:

```
trim start [length|=end]
   The optional length parameter gives the length of audio to output after the 
   start sample and is thus used to trim off the end of the audio.
   Alternatively, an absolute end location can be given by preceding it with 
   an equals sign. Using a value of 0 for the start parameter will allow trimming
   off the end only.
```

Comment: Nope, neither worked for me :S
The file ends up being 0 seconds long

Comment: There is no soxi.exe file in my extraction :S

Comment: I have 1.4.4.0 btw
I tried:
sox tracks\01_1.mp3 ntracks\01_1.mp3 trim 2.0 0.19
But it just set the file to 0
i even tried
sox tracks\01_1.mp3 ntracks\01_1.mp3 trim 00:00:02.0 00:00:00.19

Comment: I want to pass a list of [[start, end ]] times and an audio  so that those portions are silenced out. what would be best way to achieve this using sox or ffmpeg? i.e

Comment: @kRazzyR: Post this as a new question adhering to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines

Comment: @Thor Hi! Yes. I posted a new question too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48161567/silence-out-regions-of-audio-based-on-a-list-of-time-stamps-using-sox-and-pyth

Comment: Specific thanks / upvote to whoever wrote "`If you want to trim 195 milliseconds from the end of the file, use gerald's answer.`"  Perhaps it was @Thor?

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried using the reverse command like this:

```
sox tracks\5_7.mp3 ntracks\05_7.mp3 reverse trim 0.195 reverse
```

This should throw away the last 0.195 milliseconds of the file (it works for me).

Comment: This is what I needed.  Thanks to @Thor for pointing me here!

Answer (score 7):

you should use like this to trim in milliseconds

```
trim 26.26 =32.3245678
```

which means it will trim 26.26 seconds to exactly up to 32.3245678 seconds

this will give you the accurate result

with this `=` option we need to give end of the time instead of the duration with preceding of `=`

I hope this will resolve your problem

Comment: sox C:/wamp/www/audio/092A-0942-0930-0940.ogg ./output/1426308767635.ogg trim 0.000 =0.101